# OSGi HTTP Client Post Method

Tags: http, post, osgi

I have just started to learn OSGi. Recenly got stuck with an issue. How can I post data

to a HTTP server from an OSGi bundle without using external bundles/framework?

I will like to see code sample of a simple OSGI bundle which acts as a HTTP

client and can send a string to a HTTP server (tornado, in my case).

I have searched around a lot. But I got no direct solutions. There are restlets, Felix and all type of solutions. The only thing I want is to send data from an OSGi bundle to a HTTP server without using any external frameworks. Is it possible?

Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Posting data to an HTTP server has nothing to do with OSGi at all, plain Java is all you need.

If you want to go really barebones, you can use an [HttpURLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) to post your data. You can also choose a little more comfort, and use the [Apache HttpComponents Client](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/).